# eclipse plugin: add image to browser

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have created an Eclipse plugin which displays a browser with a URL as follows:

```
browser.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
browser.setUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Also I am able to get the animated image from the bundle as follows:

```
Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/sample.gif"), null)).createImage();
```

How could I add the **Image** to the **browser** on run time execution?

Comment: Where do you want the image to display?  In the browser widget?

Comment: at center of the browser widget

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the Browser widget to display a URL, the widget will display the contents of that URL.

If you want to display your own content, you'll have to use the [setText()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#setText(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) method.

Perhaps you can create html that includes the URL you want in an IFRAME and compose the rest of the html with your own content?

As for the image, I'm sure there are ways to include the image in the constructed HTML ... or you can base64 encode the data and include it in the constructed HTML.  See [Can I embed a .png image into an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page)