# how to youtube thumbnails link replace with site link

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I have problem youtube video and thumbnails block in our country and I want to run youtube api for getting these data , but problem is thumbnails links show like these link

[image]

I want to its show through my site link with my server like

https://img.example.com/vi/T0Jqdjbed40/default.jpg

I try to replace url with string replace function but its not work please tell me how to run through my site link like some site show like playit , vube.pk , flix

Comment: The link to your second image is dead.

Answer (score 0):

As a purely theoretical thing, you can replace sections of a string using the [str_replace](https://php.net/str_replace) function:

```
str_replace(
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/T0Jqdjbed40/default.jpg",
    "://i.ytimg.com", "://img.example.com");
```

This will keep the `http://` or `https://` protocol in place.

---

For your use case, again purely theoretically, you would want to download the resource yourself, and then provide it to the end user. To get the data using [file_get_contents](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for example:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

You culd then potentially embed the image data directly into the page itself - see this SO question: [Can I embed a .png image into an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page)

You should probably check youtube's terms of service before attempting anything...

Comment: yes i already check it replace function but after replace its not show image

Comment: @SameedAlam that's because `https://img.example.com/vi/T0Jqdjbed40/default.jpg` probably doesn't exist, you haven't created it. Try putting it in your web browser - the image needs to link to a file that actually exists. The second half of my answer is important.