# How do I embed an image in my T4 template?

Tags: c#, t4

I can't find any MSFT resources on this, and am unsure if it's even possible. But could someone please advise how I would go about embedding an image in a T4 template please?

Comment: The T4 template generates c# code, so what do you mean by embed an image in it?

Comment: in the `.tt` template file, I'd like for there to be a static image included

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense, sorry. It's like saying 'I want to show an image in a text file' and no, you can't do that. What's the reason you want to do that / the desired goal?

Comment: The .tt is executed on save, so you should be able to decode an image and save it to disk upon saving of the file. But why don't you include the file in the first place? Is the image generated?

Comment: So from my understanding, the `.tt` file is interpreted and a text file is produced from the template. I want to produce a HTML file, and have an image in that

Comment: So your question is how to embed an image in an html file...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page

Comment: HTML does not allow binary images to be directly embedded.  You have to convert binary image to a BASE 64 string before inserting in html.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: If that's how you do it, then yes. But given I'm unfamiliar with T4, I wasn't sure it was that simple.

Comment: This has nothing to do with T4

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked. but it may still help someone.

**Assuming you already know how to insert data model from backend to T4 Template.**

You will need a string variable in which you will implement the "img" tag such as:

```
string Image = "< img alt = 'Embedded Image' src ="'" + BASE64 + "' />";
```

where BASE64 is your image in BASE64 string.

So example result of what would be stored in your variable would be

```
<img alt='Embedded Image' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJUAAACyCAYAAABLC43BAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU' />
```

*Of course I didnt use real Base64String, only part of it. as it would be extremely long*

Later in the t4 template define your model

```
<#+ public Model Data {get;set;} #>
```

and use

`<#= Data.Image #>`

this line of code inside your `<body>` Tag to insert the imageTag.