# Qt 5.6.2 : How to copy 1 pixmap + 1 text in the clipboard?

Tags: qt, clipboard

I can copy a pixmap into the windows clipboard with Qt. It's ok.
But now, I would like to add a text before my image (pixmap) but it doesn't work.

This my code :

```
    QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    clipboard->setText("bla bla"); // I added this line
    clipboard->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

I think that I need to create a htlm with my enriched text but I don't know how to add an pixmap (the image data without an URL)

How can I do that ?

Comment: I found something interesting here : https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/embed-images-with-data-urls.shtml

Comment: explain yourself better, what do you hope to get visually?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution a while ago. I wrote an html string with an embedded png like that : [Can I embed a .png image into an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page)

ps: I converted my pixmap on fly into a png / base64 / string.