# Is there any method to store image in html page.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, storage

I want to know that is there any method in which I can directly store an image in the HTML page rather than providing the path. I mean as we can embed text in the HTML page, can we embed image in the HTML page. For example, I do not want that image to be stored somewhere else in the folder it must be stored directly in the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I embed a .png image into an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page)

Comment: nest time please do us all a favor and search first.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert image to base64, and pass it as a background or in an img's src parameter.

You can convert images to base64 online.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```