# Convert BitMap Image to string or jpeg

Tags: c#, html, image, windows-8, bitmap

I am trying to convert a Bit map image in my windows 8 app (C#), to a string or a regular jpeg.

I am doing thins because I am trying to print the image in some html.

The image is stored in variable `itemImage`.

When I try to print in in the HTML using the image tag it doesn't show up.

```
"<img src=" +itemImage + "/>"
```

When I print in in the html in shows up as `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`

How do I show the Image in the html?

Comment: You could convert it to base64 and that can be used in html. [Example conversion](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the image out as a separate file, and then point the `<img href="">` tag at that file. Alternatively, set the `href` to a callback line which calls your program with arguments that cause the program to emit the image data.

OR, [you can embed the image data directly in the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002147/html-embed-image-directly-in-html-old-school-style), but that is a very EVIL hack and you absolutely should not under any circumstances do this. I did not mention this option. :)

Comment: Could you please explain why it is 'EVIL' for this case? I think it is just a nice and simple solution for printing a memory bitmap. Otherwise perhaps even more appropriate for captchas.